# How to automatically apply a password to all posts within a custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, user-access, password

I am creating a custom post type, for which I want all posts to be password-protected with the same password.

I realize that I can set a password on a post-by-post basis from within the admin panel, however this seems tedious and prone to error/forgetfulness.

I'm sure there's a way to make this happen with some kind of filter, but I just don't know where to start.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make all the posts for a post type `password protected` with the same password then you can do run an [`update query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#UPDATE_rows) like below to make this happen.

Use the following code in the active theme's **`functions.php`** file.

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->update( 
    $wpdb->prefix . 'posts', 
    array( 'post_password' => 'wpse' ), // Replace wpse with your password 
    array( 'post_type' => 'post' ), // Replace post with the custom post type
    array( '%s' ), 
    array( '%d' ) 
);
```

The above will make all the post type `post` password protected with the password as `wpse`.

Comment: Thanks I will try this and see! But will this only apply to already-published posts? The goal is to have this feature applied to new posts as they are being created. (Having it applied to previously-published posts would be a nice bonus though.)

Comment: it will be applicable to all the posts, new and already existing :)

Comment: Excellent, thank you! I will try it and report back.

Comment: I was thinking about another way to solve this problem which does not involve direct database manipulation.

Would it be possible to set up a filter using "password_edit_pre" and have it automatically apply a password to only posts from within the custom post type inside the WP admin panel when these posts are being created? (See http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/password_edit_pre )

I think I'd prefer this solution if possible. I realize this method will not apply a password to already-published posts, but that's not much of a concern because this is a brand new site.

Comment: Yes we can look for a filter to do so, and regarding your concern about the password being applied to the previous posts, then I have tested it and it applies to all the post previous and new.

Comment: Thanks! If you can supply any code on how to use that filter it would be greatly appreciated!