# Change page password every day (predictable password ;) )

Tags: php, users, password

I've got a WP page containing a survey. 
The survey will be accessed by different people everyday (for simplicity say everyday for the whole year).
I would like to password protect it and the password suppose to be changed everyday at midnight-ish.
However to some extent the password should be formatted to be predictable for managers sharing the link to the survey (they can easily work-out what's today's password)- but not predictable to the end users :)

So for instance the password on the 2nd of Oct could look like

```
var day = currentDay
var month = currentMonth
var pass = "D!" + month + "K#" + day //formula passed to the managers
```

resulting in that day's password: D!10k#2

This solution doesn't have to be *supa strong*, it's just to protect the survey from overuse by "not expected" people.
I've read [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/174814/automatically-change-page-password) topic but it does not seem relevant that much.

Many thanks for reading and for any help :)
Enjoy your Friday!

Rafał

//EDIT
It seems I would have to create a real CRON job triggering wp_cron and actually the code from [the post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/174814/automatically-change-page-password) I mentioned before would have to be modified to generate password according to the formula above. I know very little about php, so any help would be appreciated. No explanation regarding implementation is required though :)

//EDIT 2
Actually I find the post very useful, it just needs some tweaking, but I'm far from calling myself php delveloper so wanted ask for help.

I removed all scheduling code and left with a tiny bit of php code. Would the below snippet be enough to work if triggered by real CRON job?
And what would be the formula to use marked below: FORMULA?

```
<?php
    add_action( 'wpse_change_pass_event', function()
{
        $slug = 'hello-world'; // Edit this post slug to your needs!

$formula = WHAT HERE? :)

       global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->update(
        $wpdb->posts,
        array( 'post_password' => $formula ),
        array( 'post_name'     => $slug    ),
        array( '%s' ),
        array( '%s' )
    );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It need not be very complicated. You can simply create a pattern like `2018-09-07-ABC` (suffix of `ABC`) for the date `2018-09-07`.

Set up the password creation/validation logic like `password = md5('2018-09-07-ABC')`.

An administrator if they know the pattern, they can anytime goto any online `md5` utility such as http://www.md5.cz and enter the pattern for current date.

Say for example today is December 25, 2018. Then they will enter `2018-12-25-ABC` and the hash will be `b21746c6db1c5323f28dd874fe60165f`

> **TIP**: You do not need to use entire 32 character password. Using first 8 characters (or any desired length) would be easier.

Sample PHP Code the generate password of length 8:

```
$md5hash  = md5(date('Ymd') . '-ABC');
$password = substr($md5hash, 0, 8);
```

> **Note**: Take care of the timezone being used at the server when generating the password.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. 
I'm very weak in writing *working* php code :)

Would snippet I added above work if triggered by real CRON job?
And what code to use to for "formula" variable?

Many thanks.

Comment: I just added the sample php code to get the password for current date.