# How do I email a new page password to somebody every month?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, password, wp-cron

I want to email the new page password to somebody every month.  I see no reason why [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/174820/117705) cannot be adapted.

First I guess I need to change this:

```
add_filter( 'cron_schedules', function( $schedules )
{
    // Our custom cron interval:
    $schedules['every_2nd_day'] = array(
        'interval'  => 2 * DAY_IN_SECONDS,
        'display'   => 'Once every second day'
    );
```

to

```
add_filter( 'cron_schedules', function( $schedules )
{
    // Our custom cron interval:
    $schedules['every_month'] = array(
        'interval'  => 1 * MONTH_IN_SECONDS,
        'display'   => 'Once every Month'
    );
```

And change the code again later where 'every_2nd_day' is referenced. Then how do I a) set up an automated email, and b) package the code as a plugin and install it?

Is that all I need do.  I assume this script is still secure, and valid for current Wordpress?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you should wrap your cron into a method:

```
function cronjob_once_every_month() {
    // Our custom cron interval:
    $schedules['every_month'] = array(
        'interval'  => 1 * MONTH_IN_SECONDS,
        'display'   => 'Once every Month'
    );
}
```

> a) set up an automated email

Then you should schedule an action:

```
if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'cronjob_once_every_month' ) ) {
    wp_schedule_event( time(), 'email_password_every_month', 'cronjob_once_every_month' );
}
```

Finally, you should hook into an action to fire the cron:

```
add_action( 'cronjob_once_every_month', 'email_password_every_month' );
function email_password_every_month() {
    wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers, $attachments );
}
```

**Tip:** you should [setup SMTP](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/75956/how-to-set-smtp-programmatically/103856#103856) because wp_mail() does not guarantee the email was received by the user.

> b) package the code as a plugin and install it?

Please, read the [official documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin).

Comment: ok thanks, will do!